# How to enable inline syntax errors/warnings highlighting in Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

I used to use Spyder IDE for my python programming and just recently switched to Atom.
In Spyder I used to get inline errors and warnings highlighting. For example if I make an unwanted indent or forgot any brackets and etc...
But in Atom I do not get any such inline warnings. Is there any setting or any plugin I can install to make it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to decide on which linter you want to use, e.g. `flake8` or `pycodestyle`. The process is the same for either choice, let's use `flake8` as an example.

1. Make sure `flake8` is installed on your system ([see documentation](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/#installation)). This will be used by the linter package we install in step 3.
2. Install the basic [`linter`](https://atom.io/packages/linter) provider for Atom. This is a requirement by the linter package in the next step.
3. Install [`linter-flake8`](https://atom.io/packages/linter-flake8)

While this example serves well to install individual linters, there are–of course–many alternatives to choose from. Since this is a matter of preference, you search what [other options](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=linter%20python) are available.

Lastly, take note that many linter packages can be further customized through package settings. Refer to their README for details.

Answer (score -1):

1. Press Ctrl + Comma  Or Open File >>Setting
2. Click on install  Tab
3. Search Linter
4. Install whatever you like

*I Recommend you also install prettier*

Linter:  for catching bugs
Prettier: which allows you to lint and format your code with a single command